# The PDF backend does not currently support the selected font

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts

Hey im trying to save a matplotlib figure as pdf file with Palatino font.
Im using the font manager as follos:

```
prop = font_manager.FontProperties(family = 'Palatino', fname = '/Users/kalex/Library/Fonts/Palatino.ttc')
```

Im getting the the error:

```
The PDF backend does not currently support the selected font.
```

Does anybody know what to do?

Comment: Hey, welcome to stackverlfow...Just make sure to put code segments in code brackets for the easiness of reading.

Comment: The answer seems pretty self explanatory: the PDF backend doesn’t support Palatino. You can try a different font, a different backend, or installing that font [manually](https://scentellegher.github.io/visualization/2018/05/02/custom-fonts-matplotlib.html).

Answer (score 9):

I ran into the same problem when I upgraded my mac to Catalina and did a fresh install of Anaconda Python.  Out of the box, without trying to load any special font, I got the same "The PDF backend does not currently support the selected font." error.

I found the solution [here](http://phyletica.org/matplotlib-fonts/).

Here is what I added to my Python script:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rc
rc('font',**{'family':'serif','serif':['Palatino']})
plt.rcParams['pdf.fonttype'] = 42
```

Comment: I have the same problem in Julia, any idea how to fix it?